# How do I send my request body as text using $http.post?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, post, body-parser

Also using npm's body-parser, how could I send the data in

```
$http.post('/',data)
```

so that when I receive it with

```
app.route('/').post(function(req,res){
  var body_better_be_a_string = typeof req.body;
})
```

req.body should be a string type. Have tried but req.body always comes back as [object Object], need req.body to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify(req.body);` will give you a string
The reson being is im guessing the req.body is a json object and when the `[object Object]` appears you are trying the view it. If you use JSON.stringify it will be parsed to string

Comment: When I do..

console.log('JSON.stringify(req.body) : ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

I get this in the console...

JSON.stringify(req.body) : {}

So I get back the object notation brackets as string rather than the string conversion of the JSON.ody))

Answer (score 0):

The Express docs specify that the data sent in req.body is a list of key value pairs, so if, for example, you are sending 'application/json' you could use JSON.stringify(req.body) to ensure that it is of type string for further manipulations: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Additionally, it might help if you updated your questions with the reason "why" you need it to be a string. Is there some manipulation you are trying to implement that isn't working?

Also, you could include the other parts of your Node script that use the body-parser since those may be relevant to the answer.

Comment: JSON.stringify(req.body) give me back this value: {}.    So instead of the string representation of the JSON it gives me the object notation as a string. I also commented out my body-parser but I still get an object as my req.body.

Comment: Can you update the Angular code block to show the actual contents of the data variable you are sending in the post request.

Comment: I have decided to replace my request body from text to JSON instead and using JSON.stringify(), it has been working fine.